# wcf 4.0 service on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, wcf, c#-4.0

I am currently developing a service with wcf 4.0 (visual studio 2010 RC).

When I try my service on the Visual Studio Development Server, it all works perfect.

However, when I tree to run my service on IIS7 on a windows 7 machine, the service doesn't work anymore. (I already changed the framework version on my application pool).

When I call an operation on the service, like the default operation GetData when I create a service, I get an error.
I used the WCF test client to connect to the service.

When I call the operation on the service, the Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger shows the following message:

> An unhandled win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe
>
> The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this proces, the JIT debugger must be run as an administrator. Would you like to debug the proces?

As far as I know, I am running Visual Studio as an administrator and this is probably the process that starts the JIT debugger.
The only option I have is to debug the W3WP process, which is probably not the right thing to do.

What can I do the make the Service to run on IIS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already solved my problem, it was the ApplicationPoolIdentity that was blocking everything.

Comment: You should use the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` for security reasons.